# ASP.Net Core MVC/WebApi - talking to each other over HTTP?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a theoretical (and probably foolish) question about web api and an mvc webapp in .Net Core.
Seeing as they overlap in Core, it's even easier to have an api and visual app in the same project, responding to different routes - great!

But, there's something architecturally fundamental which I always struggle with :  Let's say I had a web api, which other services use to do some data things and some custom actions etc. 
Then, I also have a big mvc app, this is the central app (let's say for argument).. 
Here's the question.

1) Should the mvc app be making webapi calls over http
(even though they will likely run on the same box - they dont have to of course), 
2) Should the mvc app be sharing the service and repository classes with the webapi?
3) Should the mvc app be programatically calling webapi from mvc?
(i.e. injecting the webapi classes into mvc controllers - therefore having a dependency on deployment, but abstracting the api logic and avoiding http)

Please don't let me know if this is stupid question...

Comment: You can think of your WebApi and MVC apps as interfaces of your shared application business logic. Therefore, i don't see the point in the overhead you bring (by making one call the other), when you can actually separate the business logic layer (services, repos) in a common dll.

Comment: Yeah I tend to think that the traditional way of just reusing code and injecting the same service and repo classes into any mvc/api apps is the way forward.  Another thing I thought about was api controllers being a base for the equivalents in the mvc app.  Then any api actions and implicitly available in the mvc app.... a good idea?